# Error creating or submitting a task in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am getting the error "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 4194304 bytes" while I am trying to export certain pixel values clipped to the study area.

I am using the following code:

```
Export.image.toAsset({
image: ex,
description: 'imageToAssetExample',
assetId: 'exampleExport',
scale: 30,
region: geometry,
});
```

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/35db26b2991220ae108059ee71cac39f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared your geometry `users/Jyoti/China_Coastal_Buffer`. Perhaps that geometry is overly complicated. You could try to upload a new EE table with a simplified geometry (or just use a simple polygon, like the one you've included in the script).

When you've solved that problem, you'll probably also get another error:

> Error: Export too large: specified n pixels (max: 100000000).
>   Specify higher maxPixels value if you intend to export a large area.

To solve this, specify maxPixels when exporting:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0c335f4ea2e82dca3be670207b5a00e0

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests your area is to large to export in one go:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/usage

You could consider breaking up the export in tiles, reduce the scale or some other suggestion as is explained here: 
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging